# Detecting tick marks with python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, rectangles, edge-detection

So I am given an image of a box and within the box are many tick marks with various sizes just like a ruler. As depicted below:

[This is the input picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw0KK.png)

Where I am at so far is that with edge detection I am only able to detect the outer rectangle as a rectangle but not any of the tick marks within the rectangle. Code shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


image = cv2.imread('images\Ruler.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 200)
cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

corner_points = []


for index, cnt_points in enumerate(cnts):
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnts[index], True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnts[index], 0.02 * perimeter, True)
    corner_points.append(approx)


    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(corner_points[index])
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

print(corner_points)
cv2.imshow("Contour", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would like the resulting image to look something like this image represented below:

[Ideal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q49cl.png)

As you can see both the tick marks (in red outline) and the outer rectangle (in green outline) are not only detected but you are able to distinguish a tick mark from the outer rectangle. I am also trying to obtain pixel location of the corner points of the tick marks as well as seen in my code where i store the corner points into "corner points = []"

Also i am not sure if tick marks are considered as thick lines or rectangles. so the location corner points can either be just the 2 end points of the tick mark "line" or they could be 4 vertices of the tick mark "rectangle".

Answer (score 0):

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('images/Ruler.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
h, w, _ = img.shape

bw = img > 128
corner_points = []
# if the pixel length of a line is higher than this threshold
# add the start and end points to corner_points
accepted_length = 10

for i in range (0, h):
    start = -1  # the first True pixel in the row
    stop = -1  # the first False pixel after start
    for j in range (0, w):
        if bw(i,j) and start is -1:
            start = j
        if start is not -1 and not bw(i,j):
            stop = j
            # I added 50 here to avoid adding floor and ceil lines
            if stop - start > accepted_length and stop - start < 50:
                corner_points.append([start end])
            continue
```

Comment: I tried to run your code but does not seem to compile

Comment: @1acle I didn't test it. The idea here is to add each horizontal line to `corner_points` except the top and the bottom. If the length of a horizontal line is between some threshold (10 and 50 here, can be changed), that means it is not the endpoints o a vertical line and it is not the top or bottom edge. If you can compile it, please make an edit request to correct the mistakes. If this is not what you want but you want a general approach, I suggest you using [Hough Line Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html).